# How people can get infected by Malware? What are the best security practices in Windows?

Tags: malware, audit

Nowadays, Operating systems are providing good security mechanisms and it requires user interaction to install any software. Still, people get infected by malware. I was wondering how people get infected by malware, although they know what software are they installing? Can malware bypass that user interaction required to install that software? What things should the user do to protect themselves from installing a malware?

What advice should you give to someone who recently got infected by malware?

Comment: "regular users are very computer savvy and understand the risks": No they're not, and no they don't. Apart from that, your question is much too broad. Try to ask something more specific.

Comment: Well, regular users are not tech savvy and operating systems have poor security mechanisms... That's why they get infected with malware.

Comment: I think your question is a little broad, but one possible answer is that the people with malware have a stronger (often economic) incentive to infect systems than the people getting infected have to defend them. http://krebsonsecurity.com/ is a good resource to explore how the economics of malware work. It is also a matter of the fact defence needs to be constantly perfect to be effective, where an attack needs to work once to be effective - there is an asymmetry in favour of the 'attackers'.

Comment: I tried to make it more specific. Let me know if that works.